# How can I write double horizontal arrow in Math Jax?

Tags: support, mathjax

[image]

I wish to know how to write the double horizontal arrow as shown above, in Mathjax.

Could the close voters please say where the code for this command is in close target?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Leucippus Perhaps you can indicate where this is answered in the tutorial? I looked but couldn't find anything pertinent.

Comment: To the OP, I presume any LaTeX solution will work fine with MathJax, unless you are forced to load some specific packages that are not available on MathJax. So, preferably look for a LaTeX solution first, taking the help from [tex.se] if needed.

Comment: There is a subsection of [this Answer about Additional Decorations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13081/3111) called "General Stacking" that might be useful.  Some combination of `\stackrel`, `\overset`, and `\underset` seems apt.

Comment: @Leucippus - OP should have indicated that they tried to find it in the tutorial+reference, so your comment is apropos, but I also tried searching it (albeit cursorily) and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my naive try, using `\stackrel` with an `\overset` long right arrow and an `\underset` with another long right arrow:

$$ F(A_0) \stackrel{\overset{F(f_4f_3)F(f_2f_1)}{\longrightarrow}}{\underset{F(1_{A_4})F(f_4)F(f_3f_2)F(f_1)}{\longrightarrow}} F(A_4) $$

The obvious problem is that the long right arrow construct doesn't "know" how to extend to cover the under- or over-text fully.  So instead something like this:

$$ F(A_0) \stackrel{\underrightarrow{\phantom{F(A)}F(f_4f_3)F(f_2f_1)\phantom{F(A)}}}{\scriptsize{\overrightarrow{F(1_{A_4})F(f_4)F(f_3f_2)F(f_1)}}} F(A_4) $$

gets us closer to your image.  This uses `\underrightarrow` and `\overrightarrow`.  The section of the tutorial I linked to in my Comment above (and its Comments) might help a motivated Reader to adjust sizes better.

I find not all of the [Special Latex commands](http://www.combinatorics.net/weblib/options/style.html) for font sizing work in `MathJax`.

One final stab to improve the vertical centering of first and last terms:

$$ \raise .8em {F(A_0)} \stackrel{\underrightarrow{\phantom{F(A)}F(f_4f_3)F(f_2f_1)\phantom{F(A)}}}{\scriptsize{\overrightarrow{F(1_{A_4})F(f_4)F(f_3f_2)F(f_1)}}} \raise .8em {F(A_4)} $$